# How can I deal with senior colleagues constantly getting my name wrong?

Tags: professionalism, intervention

I work in the UK and I have a fairly normal "British" name. Having worked in my company for three years with my name plastered all around my desk, my person and my email, some senior colleagues still don't get my name right. This has led to serious problems when, for example, a group email gets sent around with actions for "Jill Bloggs" when my name is actually "Jane Doe", or worse, for "JB".

Mostly I just shrug it off and ignore it, maybe quietly changing my name to be the correct one where I can, however the most recent occurrance has led to a client being upset that (as far as they could see) a different resource was working for them than had been promised.

How should I gently remind people what my name is? When should I do it; immediately or quietly at a later date? I don't get much face to face contact with the majority of my colleagues so it's difficult to physically pull them aside.

Comment: Was the responsible person aware of the problem it had caused to the client?? what was the reaction on that front

Comment: @Brandin When it happened there was a bit of eye-rolling and a general air of "Silly client, can't he see that Jill Bloggs is similar to Jane Doe? It's obvious!!" Obviously the more sensible people involved just apologised to the client and explained there'd been a mix up but no other actions were actually taken.

Comment: @GrahamBorland If it helps, over the last couple of years I have been called Amanda, Ruth, Julia, Rebecca, Elizabeth and Sarah (none of which are my first name), with a mix of my actual surname and other common british names like Baker, Brown, etc. This isn't just mixing up something like Jo/Joanna/Joanne (also not my name).

Comment: Are you the only person this issue happens to or is it a more general problem?

Comment: @Ilythya — At this point, have you considered officially changing your name to "Jill Bloggs" ?

Comment: @MartinSmith the other female member of my department also suffers to an extent

Comment: ... alright Dave? :-)

Comment: @Ilythya Out of curiosity, has this improved at all since you posted this, with or without action on your part? I remember being baffled that colleagues would get your name so drastically wrong and reading that only the two women in the department seem to suffer from this had me check the calendar year on your post, hoping against hope that it somehow arrived on this site from the sixties.

Comment: Context ... is this a Jonathan vs. Jon or a Dick vs. Richard ... or a Maria vs. Marrrrria ... ?  I am a Jonathan only ... and as much as I hate it, I permit shortening to Jon because it is culturally acceptable even though I don't think it should be ...  I realize I am late to the game, but in coming late, I don;t see this specified adequately ... diminutive shortenings are different than just blatant errors ... ,e.g., calling me Fior instead of Jonathan ...

Comment: @oemb1905 as per my earlier comment, over the last couple of years I have been called Amanda, Ruth, Julia, Rebecca, Elizabeth and Sarah, none of which are my first name - and that's not even starting on the surname variations.

Comment: @Ilythya well in that case I agree with the answer submitted ... Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This carelessness about your name has gone from affecting just you to affecting your firm's business. So it has gone from just rude to entirely unacceptable.

When someone gets your name wrong, you should *immediately* intervene, using the medium in which the error was made, saying:

> With respect, my name is Jane Doe, not Jill Bloggs.

If the error is made over email, you should do it, with a reply-all, like this:

> On Tuesday, Joe Mgr wrote:
>
> > We are assigning Ian Smith and Jill Bloggs to the TPS account.
>
> Joe:
>   With respect, my name is Jane Doe, not Jill Bloggs. You may recall that the 
>   people at Acme Rocket Sleds were annoyed by this confusion over my name. 
>   I would appreciate your use of my correct name.

If the error is made in person, speak up right away.

You might even go for the over-the-top humorous approach, and wear a large tag for a few days saying "Hello, my name is Jane Doe."

In any case it's wise, and by no means offensive, for you to be assertive about correcting this. What's at stake? Your good name!

Comment: Just want to add that you need to do it with the correct tone and attitude, you are just clarifying in polite manner.

Comment: I agree with the answer, but would like to point out one point. I wouldn't answer to all. If I understood your answer correctly there are only a small number of people "mixing-up" the names. By answering to all you publicly humiliate your superior with no obvious upside. By giving him the possibility that this was a mistake you let him keep his face. By quoting the serious incident you remind him however that this behavior is not acceptable for you.

Comment: @magu I would say as this problem has been a constant. reply-all is still inappropriate, but after a few one-on-one attempts to correct it fail. It's fair to respond in this manner with whomever their supervisor is. (As far as the project goes... if it's actual assignments then it is fair to reply to all and say "The task is assigned to Jane Doo, there is no Jull Bloggs here"

Comment: This is a sensible answer. Except that I would send the e-mail reply to the sender rather than to all.

Answer (score 12):

I think a lot of the other answers sound too aggressive for my tastes, especially if this has been going on for a couple years and just now you stir up a big fuss about it.

I would just casually notify everyone of the issue with the client and ask that everyone call you by your specific name so that there aren't any more issues like that.  I'd imagine that most people would find the situation humorous, and that would help them remember.

Comment: I think the problem is that if it had been every week I would have already done something about it. The fact it crops up maybe once every couple of months means that I tend to just shrug it off as somebody having a busy day and getting mixed up. It's then all good for another couple of months at which point it happens again.

Comment: Bringing up the issue in front of the client is NOT a good way to handle it - your company needs to be on the same page prior to bringing in a client - you don't want to person to say "Oh really? THAT'S your name?" in front of a client, so don't give them the opportunity - plan it out as best you can internally first. Surprising a senior person in front of a client is a very aggressive move, and one that will almost always backfire.

Comment: @user2813274 I am not suggesting to bring it up in front of the client, just to remind everyone what happened with the client...

Comment: @user2813274 I'm not sure that was what was being suggested to be honest.

Comment: @Ilythya I read the "notify everyone" as including the client, and had no mention of excluding them or doing anything internally prior to that.

Comment: Humour's definitely a good way to go: good natured embarrassment is memorable without harming relationships. How about a **"Jill Jar"** (like a "swear jar") where anybody who says your wrong name has to put in, say, £2, which goes towards a team social fund or charity?

Comment: @user568458 — I love the idea of the "Jill Jar" !

Answer (score 10):

I would remind the sender of such an e-mail immediately after I recognize their error. You could for example write back:

"I would like to kindly remind you that my name is Jane Doe, and not Jill Bloggs, as you have written. Please do your best to get my name right from now on. Spelling my name wrong has already led to misunderstandigs with a client once. Please help to avoid this."

If you have the opportunity, talk directly to this person, instead of or in addition to the e-mail.

Comment: You could consider "accidently " misspelling" or pronouncing the persons that has done this name in an internal  meeting to make a point

Comment: @Pepone I think that would very much depend on your relationship with the person involved. I would be uncomfortable coming across as too aggressive or rude with somebody senior than me.

Comment: @Ilythya: professionalism is a word that gets thrown around a lot, but fundamentally it means 'doing your job'. if clients are affected by this and you don't take action because you are worried about being offensive then you are being unprofessional by neglecting your duties for personal reasons. likewise for someone senior to take offense and do anything about it is unprofessional of them for the same reason... or in short: if everyone just does their job at the most basic level this shouldn't even be a concern.

Comment: @Ilythya You don't have to be aggressive or offensive to correct somebody's mistake. I know you mostly shrug it off and that's great. But remember that if anyone has the right to be offended, it's you.

Comment: @jheriko As far as the client was concerned I hadn't noticed (not having been part of any discussions) until I showed up on the day to see their confused and slightly upset faces. Obviously when I got back to the office I raised it, although by that time the damage was done.

Answer (score 2):

I would forward the client's e-mail that requests Jill Bloggs to the person who sent it originally, and ask them who this Jill Bloggs person is. 
This is a misunderstanding that was created by the senior colleague, and thus should be resolved by them. You have done your part by bringing it up to them - you could even suggest hiring in the next person named "Jill Bloggs" to do the job and keep the customer happy.

Comment: @Ilythya asked about "gently reminding people what her name is". Your answer does not really answer her question, does it? And it's not a very gentle approach.

Comment: @prockel - an internal e-mail is just about the gentlest way possible - the thing is that this has been an ongoing issue, and anything less is likely to be ignored and ineffective. Physical interactions were mentioned as difficult to pull off, and an e-mail to the client is necessary, but not from the OP.

Comment: This is not constructive. Jane Doe knows full well that the name "Jill Bloggs" is being used to refer to her so she should just correct the mistake. Playing dumb about it just causes confusion.

Comment: @DavidRicherby only alternatives is to say nothing and just let them get on with calling you that, or to ignore anything addressed to that name and probably lose your job over it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I didn't realise that I was being called Jill Bloggs until I turned up at the client's office. Given the vast array of different names I've been assigned, it's often impossible to tell that one is supposed to refer to me until it's too late.

Comment: @Ilythya Oh, I see. It's even more complicated and confusing than I thought! This is something you definitely need to get fixed. As has been said elsewhere, this isn't just the personal issue that these people don't respect you enough to get your name right but it's also a business issue, since the company might, for example, miss a deadline because you didn't do something because you had no way of knowing it had been assigned to you.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - it doesn't matter if Jane Doe knows or not, since they aren't the one who sent the client the wrong information - the person who did that needs to know (and obviously they don't, so they need a reminder), and then fix their mistake - but why would someone make an assumption about what the senior colleagues meant - allow them to explain themselves such that Jane Doe does not make any assumptions about themselves being the one referred to (even if it's an obvious assumption) - it's just playing safe.

Comment: @Ilythya — It seems that some event such as a company lunch has to be organized so that people know each other.

Answer (score 2):

I am incredibly terrible at remembering names, mostly with new people I am working with on a team. I had a similar situation where I went to a customer and indicated that John Smith would be working on a customers project, when in fact it was George Doe.

Of course this also affected the customer, and as a result George Doe was upset etc. He contacted me via email and indicated that I had forgotten his name and had incorrectly introduced him to a customer, cc-ing my manager. Of course this was not intentional on my part, however i now make a mental note to always make a proper note of the new guys name.

Perhaps its would be best to take a similar approach, if you have a team meeting, bring it up in the meeting and indicate that it is affecting clients. Also ensure that managers are aware that it has become an issue. Once clients are affected it should be regarded as serious.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking a humorous tact.  Make a "My Name Is" card with your photo (a funny one would likely be best), and the name you'd like to be known by.  Print this out on something sturdy that can be placed on a desk, and hand them to everyone with whom you work regularly that gets your name wrong.

Hand this out in person, you can explain it as "Some clients have been really confused due to people messing up my name - here is something to help you remember."

Answer (score 0):

Most answers here are way too aggressive. You should correct the error but in a calm and easy going manner. Just reply-all with:

> Jill Bloggs?

Be sure that your email signature has your full name in it and you are done.

Comment: Playing dumb doesn't help. The manager is incorrect. Playing dumb results in the manager being incorrect and confused, making the situation worse, not better. Correcting somebody's mistake is not an inherently aggressive act.

Comment: Because passive aggressive is better than just straight aggressive?

Comment: This is a clever answer.

Comment: @ReallyTiredOfThisGame — I see nothing aggressive in this answer.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco - This answer is in the a form that would be considered passive aggressive, by pretending not to know that a slight has been given instead pretending to think they are talking about someone else.